# Where should my jQuery code go in the Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get my jQuery to work when I add it to the HTML file. However, I want the onclick function to trigger changes via jQuery and it is not working, any ideas why?

```
let startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
startButton.onclick = () => {
    if (currentlyPlaying === false) {
        gameInitiate()
    }
    $('document').on('click', function(){

        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    })
    
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Also, you should probably not add event listeners within the listener for an event.

Comment: Btw. such a mix of native JavaScript and jQuery syntax, is really rather ugly. You should do the element selection and event handling using the proper jQuery methodology here to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your JS code after the DOM has loaded. As such you need to either place the `<script />` tag referencing it just before the `</body>`, or you can put it in the `<head>`, but you need to wrap your JS code in a document.ready handler.

Regarding the code itself, note that if you've included a JS library in the page it's best practice to be consistent in its use. In addition you should not nest event handlers, and `$('document')` needs to be `$(document)`. With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => { // <- document.ready handler
  $('#start-button').on('click', e => {
   if (!currentlyPlaying) {
     gameInitiate();
   }
  });
  
  let $doc = $(document).on('click', () => {
    // perhaps check if currentlyPlaying is true here?
    $doc.css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, I'm not quite getting it to work but I think I get the logic now. I'll spend a little time with it now and see. Thank you!